# Subscribe to observables in order and do actions in between

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, concatenation, subscribe

I've tried to subscribe 3 interdependent observables in the right order with the rxjs operator concat. Between the first and the second observable and after the last one have to be done some actions. The biggest problem: the result of the first one has to be passed to the second one. I've tried a few things. For example:

```
let foo = {};
concat(
  observable1().pipe(map(result => foo.id = result)),
  observable2(foo),
  observable3().pipe(map(() => console.log('ready')))
).subscribe();
```

Nothing worked like expected. The observables will be subscribed in the right order, but the result of the first subscription won't be passed to the second. The Angular version is 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for `concatMap`

In this example, I am not sure if it is correct output, provide more details

```
import { of, concat } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, map } from "rxjs/operators";

let foo = {};
obs1(1)
  .pipe(
     map(result => {
      foo["id"] = result;

      return foo || result
    }),
    concatMap(resultOfFirst => obs2(resultOfFirst)),
    concatMap(resultOfSecond => obs3())
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
function obs1(simpleData) {
  return of(simpleData);
}

function obs2(simpleData) {
  return of(simpleData);
}

function obs3() {
  return of("ready");
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-uqhyei?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Comment: I'd add that in this case, `switchMap`, `mergeMap`, and `concatMap` have the same final behaviours since each observable emits once and then completes.